# AJAX Function issues

Tags: jquery

I use a function to post result via Ajax. When I test to see if the function was called I add an alert. Everything works fine, but as soon as I remove alert my results are not posted... What's causing it?

```
function SendInvitesF(invType, invWho, projID) {            
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: POST",
        data: "op=sendInvites&inviteMsgType="+invType+"&invitees="+invWho+"&proj="+projID   
    });
    alert("test "+projID) // test alert <<<
}

$("#btnSend").click(function() {
    if($("#customMsg").attr("checked")) {               
        var invType = "custom";
    } else {
        var invType = "default";
    }
    var invWho = $(".radioB:checked").val();
    var projID = $("#testID").val();

    SendInvitesF(invType, invWho, projID);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are calling this function in the onclick or onsubmit event and you are not canceling the default action by returning false. Also you are not properly url encoding any of your parameters. To do this use the data hash:

```
function SendInvitesF(invType, invWho, projID) {            
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
            op: 'sendInvites',
            inviteMsgType: invType,
            invitees: invWho,
            proj: projID   
    });
    return false;
}
```

and then if you are calling this inside the onclick of an anchor:

```
// I guess btnSend is a submit button or an anchor so make sure
// you cancel the default action by returning false from the click
// callback
$('#btnSend').click(function() {
    if ($('#customMsg').attr('checked')) {               
        var invType = 'custom';
    } else {
        var invType = 'default';
    }
    var invWho = $('.radioB:checked').val();
    var projID = $('#testID').val();

    return SendInvitesF(invType, invWho, projID);
});
```

Notice how we are returning false and thus canceling the default action which would be a redirect and of course not leaving the time for the AJAX request to execute. When you put an alert at the end of the function this stops any script execution and the AJAX call has the time to hit the server.

Comment: @santa, yes, I see. Well, as I said in my answer make sure you are returning false from this .click handler.

Comment: Wow, It makes sense... However, now when I click it doesn't appear that the function is called at all...  Also I think "}" on line 10.

Comment: I also noticed that you changed all quotes to singe. I have my code withing PHP code and used " instead. Could that be an issue?..

Comment: @santa, it's just a habit I have to use single quotes in javascript. You could use double quotes if you will. It's not a problem and not what is causing the issues here.

Comment: Oops, it does post data, but the redirect obviously does not work. How do I make POST data and redirect afterwards?

Comment: @santa, in order to redirect on the client side you could use `window.location.href`.

Comment: My #btnSend is a link that also served as a submit button. Where would I add window.location.href? Should it be inside function on success?

Comment: Instead or returning false, can't I delay redirect for a second to allow AJAX script to hit my page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the alert on the success handler? to make sure that the ajax call actually went trough successfully? also, like Darin maybe you used on a onClick and forgot to cancel the default action.